# How to enable the Intl extension from twig/intl-extra

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony4, twig-extension

I've been running through the docs and couldn't find where to init `twig/intl-extra`

[The twig doc here](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/format_datetime.html) says to either use `use Twig\Extra\Intl\IntlExtension;` or to add the extension explicitly on the Twig environment

```
$twig = new \Twig\Environment(...);
$twig->addExtension(new IntlExtension());
```

I would like tpo use the second case and add explicitly to the twig environment.

In which file should I do it?

Comment: Found, thanks, had to add `Twig\Extra\Intl\IntlExtension: ~` in `services.yaml`. You should write it as an answer so I can validate it @msg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using twig with Symfony, you should register the extension as a service in your `services.yaml` file.

If installed using the `twig/extensions` flex recipe, it will provide the `config/packages/twig_extensions.yaml` file, you just have to uncomment the desired extensions (see the [original comment](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig-extensions/issues/140#issuecomment-511125247) on github).

The [default configuration](https://github.com/symfony/recipes/blob/master/twig/extensions/1.0/config/packages/twig_extensions.yaml) for reference:

```
services:
    _defaults:
        public: false
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true

    # Uncomment any lines below to activate that Twig extension
    #Twig\Extensions\ArrayExtension: null
    #Twig\Extensions\DateExtension: null
    #Twig\Extensions\IntlExtension: null
    #Twig\Extensions\TextExtension: null
```

Answer (score 4):

Above answer will not work in symfony 4. The path to Extension is different.
For example IntlExtension need to be configured like that:

```
services:
    Twig\Extra\Intl\IntlExtension: null
```